# how to disable jquery tabs onloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

how to disable the tab on load function ?. I need to disable tabs onload function and enabled onclick of save button. how to achieve this?

my code is in jsp

```
<div id="tabs1" >
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1-1" id="tabs01">Incident Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs1-2"  id="tabs02">Incident Notes</a></li>         
    </ul>
<div id="tabs1-1">
<span>This is incident info</span>
</div>
<div id="tabs1-2">
<span>This is incident Note</span>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#tabs1-2').hide();
    $('#tabs1-1').show();
    $('#tabs1 ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs1 ul li a').click(function(){ 
        $('#tabs1 ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        var currentTab =jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
        if(currentTab=="#tabs1-1"){
             $('#tabs1-2').hide();
            $('#tabs1-1').show();
        }
        else if(currentTab=="#tabs1-2"){
             $('#tabs1-1').hide();
                $('#tabs1-2').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

and enabled from onclick of save button (it is in js page)

```
function save(){
// here I need to enabled 
}
```

I need tab disabled on load ,for this what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `disabled` option:

```
$("#tabs1").tabs({
    disabled: true
});
```

Then when you want to enable the tabs, use the option method:

```
$("#tabs1").tabs("option" , disabled , false);
```

Comment: This code will need to run after the script file for jQuery UI. The error is usually generated when your code tries to run before jQuery UI is available :)

Comment: helo i used jquery i.6.4.min.js and jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js but not work this .Please suggest the appropriate library

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.17 should be fine together, load jQuery first, then jQuery UI then run your tabs code

Comment: Any more errors in the console? When you say no effect, do the tabs not work? They work but are not disabled?

Comment: they work but not disable. it work by hide and show of particular div and not by tab()